# Run Jhipster-registry locally without browser sync

Tags: npm, webpack, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm trying to build a micro-services applications with JHipster. I'm following this  [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jhipster-microservices).

I've successfully run jhipster-registry locally (I've cloned it, then run the commands `./mvnw` and `yarn start` to be able to see the applications registered). Without this yarn start I can't see anything on my browser.

But I want to run my gateway application with the browser sync and I can't because it's focused on jhipster-registry.

I've a backend micro-service on port 8081.

My gateway is configured on port 8080, `./mvnw` run successfully and I can see my application on localhost:8080. But I would like to have the hot reload when I run my `npm start` command on my gateway. I've configured my package.json to run on the port 9061 :

```
"webpack:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9061 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
"webpack:dev-verbose": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9061 --watch-content-base --profile --progress --env.stats=normal",
```

When I run npm start it says I can see my app on localhost:9001, but I'm on the jhipster-registry...

Does someone can help me ?

Comment: Why do you run `yarn start` for the registry? Just build it for prod using `./mvnw -Pprod package` and then run it using `java -jar target/jhipster-registry*.war`. This is how you will run it in production anyway and you probably don't want to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gael Marziou, I've build the package like if I was in production with the commands :

```
./mvnw -Pprod package
```

And then :

```
java -jar target/jhipster-registry*.war
```

I've had to up the memory allocated for the build in the package.json file :

```
"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
```

because I had this error : 
[image: Error]